# Custom label when using matrix in GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

Given the following quite standard workflow:

```yaml
name: Test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        ruby: [3.0, 3.1]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
    - name: Check out
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Ruby ${{ matrix.ruby }}
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: ${{ matrix.ruby }}
        bundler-cache: true
    - name: Run tests
      run: SPEC_SCOPE=all bundle exec rake
```

The separate runs of test according to the matrix are labelled like so:

[image]

For the sake of better understanding, can the way the matrix is labelled be changed from "ubuntu-latest, 3.1" to something like "ubuntu-latest, ruby-3.1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dhannanjay answered this on Github

> You can change the name for a job by providing a name property. You can access all the metadata in the job configuration.
>
> ```
> name: Run tests
>
> on: [push, pull_request]
>
> jobs:  
>   test:
>     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>     strategy:
>       matrix:
>         node-version: [12.x, 13.x]
>         mongodb-version: [4.0, 4.2]
>
>     name: Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }} - MongoDB ${{ matrix.mongodb-version }}
>
>     steps:
>     - name: …
> ```

(source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/github-actions-customize-the-job-name)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, in the [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) seems to support a custom label.

From your [discussion #9918](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9918), [Marcin Kubica](https://github.com/marcinkubica) adds in [this thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9918#discussioncomment-9024750):

> If you have:
>
> ```
>   build:
>     name: build ${{ matrix.site }}
>     strategy:
>       fail-fast: true
>       matrix:
>         site:
>           - dev:
>             some_var: ${{ vars.DEV_SOME_VAR }}
>           - prod:
>             some_var: ${{ vars.PROD_SOME_VAR }}
> ```
>
> you get `buld Object` :)
>
> [image: double label]
>
> needs an ugly hack with
>
> ```
>   build:
>     name: build ${{ matrix.site.env }}
>     needs: test
>     strategy:
>       matrix:
>         site:
>           - dev:
>             env: dev # hack for github ui job name
>             ...other stuff
>           - prod:
>             env: prod # hack for github ui job name
>             ...other stuff
> ```

Comment: As per your suggestion: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/9918

Comment: @svoop OK, thank you for this feedback. I will follow the discussion thread you have created.

Comment: It's possible after all, see https://futurestud.io/tutorials/github-actions-customize-the-job-name